# Why do we dream?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, developmental-psychology, dreams, human-factors

Most of the people have their own imagination and most of them dream about many things and some time dream about those things which they have never seen, so how we will define the fact that why do we dream?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is at risk of being closed as [not framed in psychology or neuroscience](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience). Furthermore, it is unclear how the paragraph you added supports your question "Why do we dream?" in any way. Instead, add some initial (minimal) research you have done, and elaborate on exactly what you need more information on.